# The constructor is undefined working with dynamic ViewPager

Tags: java, android, json, gridview, android-viewpager

I am getting `The constructor ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<Actors>) is undefined` in ViewPagerActivity.java

```
// The constructor ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<Actors>) is undefined
ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(fetchedList);
```

I am using [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-implementing-viewpager-into-gridview-tutorial/) tutorial to make a small photo gallery app, where i have two activities, first `GridViewActivity` and second `ViewPagerActivity`.

I want to show tapped image in a ViewPager activity when the user clicks on one of the items in the GridViewActivity

I have written code to parse images into `GridView` using Picasso lib

**Actors:**

```
public class Actors implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -236818675216044571L;

    private String image;

    public Actors() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Actors(String image) {
        super();        
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

To show `images` in a `ViewPager`, I have created another class named: ViewPagerActivity.java

**ViewPagerActivity.java:**

```
    public class ViewPagerActivity extends Activity {

    ......

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

        .....
        }


        ......

    }
}
```

And as a result i am getting complete ArrayList and a tapped item position along with image URL, but not getting what to do next to get images in a ViewPager ?

**ImagePagerAdapter.java:**

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

**Do you want to give a try at your end ?** So you may download complete code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B78ywgdV16pZRjVGZDdqUHlMTU0/view)

Comment: Do you want to open a  `ViewPager` activity when the user clicks on one of the items in the `GridViewActivity`?

Comment: hope you want the same images to be shown in view pager in a different page. you need to create a PagerAdapter and link it to your view pager object. You can refer http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: @Catalina exactly ..

Comment: Try with inflating an xml file or define layout Params of ImagevIew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am confuse, What to do next to show my GridView images into
>   ViewPager activity.

The first step would be to make `GridViewActivity` extending `Fragment`  instead of `Activity`. The second step would be to create a class that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`, override `getItem()`, to return the Fragment that contains the `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the good answer on your question
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

If your `fetchedList` is the arraylist of `Actors` model class then you need to change in your adapter constructor

```
private List<Actors> images;

public ImagePagerAdapter(List<Actors> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
```

and if is the arraylist of another class then retain the same constructor as you did. The problem is because of type mismatched arraylist in your constructor and passing the different arraylist.

Comment: I have already tried that, but getting : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Actors to ImageView at this line ImageView imageView = images.get(position); and The method removeView(View) in the type ViewGroup is not applicable for the arguments (Actors) at this line: container.removeView(images.get(position));

Comment: But in your model class you have set image as a string not for ImageView class

Comment: Exactly what do you want? Want to load images ?

Comment: @SilentKiller Yes Yes I will.

Comment: @SilentKiller what do you mean by full source code, i have written whole code my own facing issue, so just looking for help